# How to clone an element then increase the id by one

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im trying to create a form builder im approaching this by making creating elements putting them is a list group then making them draggable. This works so far however when i drag in item and place it the it disappears from the elements section this makes sense but i would like it to find the id of the item that has been selected and then copy the element but with a different id.

This is my code so far
JavaScript

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    console.log("Component Selected")
    var elem = document.querySelector(ev.target.id);
    var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = ('drag9');
    elem.after(clone);
}




<div class="row">
     <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
       <ul class="list-group">
         <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" class="list-group-item">
           <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Input</label>
             <button type="button" class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square fa-lg"></button>
               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="ControlInput1" placeholder="">
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Indexed ids is an antipattern, don't use them, they're simply not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of dynamic page creation functionality has to be done without `id` attributes, they are error prone and a nightmare to maintain.

Drag'n'Drop functionality consists of multiple events. You shouldn't do everything on `dragstart`, dropping has its own event - `drop` - during which you're supposed to append the element to the target element. And, never use inline listeners for elements. In this case it's usefull to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/1169519) `dragstart` event to the `ul` container.

When you drag an element, it should be dropped only on an element, which is an allowed parent to the element to drop (the only allowed parents of [`li` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#technical_summary) are `menu`, `ul` and `ol`, it shouldn't be dropped on a `div`).

As Drag'n'Drop API doesn't provide a property where you can store a live reference to the actually dragged element, it's best to store it in a variable when `dragstart` event fires. This tackles the need of `id` attributes and all unnecessary DOM traversing.

All this in mind, I've created a fully `id`less example code of how to implement a simple drag'n'drop, you can develope it further for your needs.

```js
const dragSrc = document.body.querySelector('.dragSrc'),
  dropPad = document.body.querySelector('.dropTarget');

let draggedElement = null;

dragSrc.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  draggedElement = e.target;
});

dropPad.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});

dropPad.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const clone = draggedElement.cloneNode(true);
  e.target.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```css
.dropTarget {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-group dragSrc">
    <li draggable="true" class="list-group-item">
      <label class="form-label">Email:
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </label>
      <button type="button" class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square fa-lg">Button</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="list-group dropTarget"></ul>
```

Comment: ... excellent answer and clean example code ...